# Is $X_t$ a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is $X_t=\int_0^t$ Wsds a martingale? I checked the conditional expectation and I have $$E[X_t/F_u]=E[\int_0^u Wsds/F_u]+E[\int_u^t Wsds/F_u]=\int_0^u Wsds+\int_u^t E[Ws]ds=X_u$$, so it does look like satisfies the property, where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you assume $\int_u^t W_s ds$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_u$. This is not true. Can you see why?

Comment: I see, thanks. I would guess because they both involve the information at time $u$, so they overlap there and not independent? Then, second part ends up being $\int_u^t E[W_s/F_u]ds=W_u(t-u)$? And clearly this is not zero and therefore it is not a martingale?